# Not able to install cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Not able to install cygwin.

I am trying to install cygwin 32 bit setup in my 64-bit OS, as we need to support 32 bit OS also. While I am trying to install after selecting all packages, setup.exe is getting crashed showing setup.exe has stopped working.

I have disabled anti virus as well.

This is my error log:

```
2020/01/02 12:17:09 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2020/01/02 12:17:09 Ending cygwin install
```

Comment: This is not the cygwin support and your is not a programming question . Use the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html for this type of help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an installation problem. Support is provided by the cygwin@cygwin.com mailing list